# Multiply each value in array using array_map function

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I'm trying to multiply each value from `array_module_rate` array.

The result should be:

- `$array_module_rate[0]` = 25
- `$array_module_rate[1]` = 15
- `$array_module_rate[2]` = 20

How I can do it?

```
$array_module_rate = array(
  '5',
  '3',
  '4'
}

$global_course = 5;

array_map(function($cal) {
  return $cal * $global_course;
}, $array_module_rate);
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of `array_map()`. It doesn't modify the array in place, it returns a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array_module_rate = array(
  '5',
  '3',
  '4'
}

$global_course = 5;

foreach($array_module_rate as $key=>$value){
   $array_module_rate[$key]=$global_course* $value;
}
```

You can use a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Use closure to send additional argument in `array_map` callback.

```
$array_module_rate = array(
  '5',
  '3',
  '4'
);

$global_course = 5;

array_map(function($cal) use($global_course) {
  return $cal * $global_course;
}, $array_module_rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the original array, you can use `array_walk` instead of `array_map`. It takes the array by reference, so if you pass the array element to the callback by reference as well, you can modify it directly.

```
array_walk($array_module_rate, function(&$cal) use ($global_course) {
   $cal *= $global_course;
});
```

Note that you need to pass `$global_course` into the callback with `use`, otherwise [it won't be available in that scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

Modern PHP has "arrow functions" which allow you to access global scoped variables within an anonymous function body.  This allows you to concisely multiply each element by the `$global_course` factor using a clean, functional approach.

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/6010123900c874b52d5537e0afec34e7/))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => $v * $global_course, $array_module_rate)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 25,
  1 => 15,
  2 => 20,
)
```